# How to call onProductPurchased in Fragment In-app Billing android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, in-app-purchase

I used this library for In-app Billing in android purchase
https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

For purchasing everything is fine but my problem is when In-app Billing event purchase call in fragment  `onProductPurchased` event don't call because `onActivityforResult` doesnt call in fragment

Fragment Code :

```
 bp = new BillingProcessor(getActivity(), Constants.KEY_BASE64_PUBLICK_KEY, this);
        bp.initialize(); // binds
   boolean isAvailable = BillingProcessor.isIabServiceAvailable(getActivity());
                if (isAvailable) {
 bp.purchase(getActivity(), SKU_Pro);
}
```

I also checked this page 
https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/issues/100

Comment: May be this can link can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: can you give me the best solution for this issue ?

Comment: I don't know why google doesn't have any clear documentation for In-app Billing  ?

Comment: I am using this Library  compile 'org.solovyev.android:checkout:1.0.0' for my in-app billing functionality. Its easy to implement and has an sample for fragment as well. may be it can help you.

Comment: @MRX I'm not able to find the sample code for fragments, where can you find it?